# Weird circuit schematics

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-regulator

I have hired a guy to design a simple voltage regulator with standard ATX connectors.

It looks weird to me; can you guys check it out, please?

[image]

1. It makes me wonder if the 12 V (most likely switching voltage/current from an ATX PSU) is somehow filtered before it goes into the TI voltage regulator. Does it even matter what sort of DC voltage goes into a buck converter? The datasheet is unclear.
2. Connector wiring looks weird; is it correct?

Comment: Why does weird mean incorrect? How have you checked?

Comment: The drawing seems poorly laid out and unnecessarily difficult to follow. One thing I notice from the datasheet is that they appear to recommend separate analog and power grounds and use different ground symbols for each. The schematic you posted doesn't differentiate and this may be a big issue when transferred to PCB.

Comment: Editing other people's questions to fix poor formatting, spelling, grammar, etc. is a standard feature of Stack Exchange sites. If you don't like it and can't get used to it, then this is probably not the place for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you go to TI's [TPS54JA20 product page](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS54JA20), to the section "Design & development" / "WEBENCH® Designer", and click on "Open Design", the <strike>sophisticated AI</strike> simple script creates a schematic like this. (You can also begin with the parameters, and it will suggest some chips.)

[image: TI Power Designer - TPS54JA20]

That guy then exported the schematic and added the connectors.

The connectors are wired correctly, but the ground pins should be connected together (routing them separately does not make sense).

It's obvious that the 'designer' did not spend any thought on filtering, but an ATX output probably does not need any.

Comment: It makes me wonder if "efficiency: 91.7%" is real for whole board or is it just a marketing hype.

Comment: There are [efficiency graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiOcz.png).

Comment: that is for regulator itself, not for whole circuit no?

Comment: It is for the circuit shown.

Comment: "the ground pins should be connected together (routing them separately does not make sense)."

Do I even need ground pins? It can be connected to ATX PCIe ground pins no?

Comment: With "ground pins", I mean all seven pins labelled "GND".